# Pandas - Create a Integer Primary Key based in string columns - python

Tags: python, pandas

I need to create a primary key based in string columns in my dataframe

```
Month       Name                   ID
01/01/2020  FileName1 - Example    1
01/02/2020  FileName2 - Example    2
01/03/2020  FileName3 - Example    3
```

I'm using the hash, but its generating the largest values, I would like that ID was the integer numbers.
This is my code

```
all_data['unique_id'] = all_data._ID.map(hash)
```

where  _ID is :

```
all_data['_ID'] = all_data['Month'].astype(str) + all_data['Name']
```

This group by return 0 for all rows

```
all_data['sequence']=all_data.groupby('_ID').cumcount()
```

Comment: The groupby returns all 0 means your unique id is in fact unique for every rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use pd.factorzie:

```
all_data['unique_id'] = pd.factorize(all_data['_ID'])[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could simply drop the index to create and use it as a primary key column.

```py
all_data.reset_index(inplace=True)
all_data.head()
```

[image: all_data_result]

Comment: Month =["01/01/2020","01/02/2020","01/03/2020"]
Name=["FileName1 - Example","FileName2 - Example","FileName3 - Example"]
ID=[1,2,3]
df=pd.DataFrame({'Month':Month,'Name':Name,'ID':ID})
df=df.set_index('ID')
print(df.index)